# HAProxy stats says all Thrift servers are down

Tags: haproxy, supervisord

I am trying to setup HAProxy to load balance a group of Thrift servers. For some reason the HAProxy stats page says the servers are all down.

Here is the current HAProxy config I am trying.

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     60000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy

defaults
    log     global
    option  dontlognull
    option redispatch
    retries 3
    maxconn 2000
    contimeout      5000
    clitimeout      50000
    srvtimeout      50000

listen stats :5000
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /
    stats auth user:pass

listen metrix :5002
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    balance leastconn
    server m1 127.0.0.1:9000 check
    server m2 127.0.0.1:9001 check
    server m3 127.0.0.1:9002 check
    server m4 127.0.0.1:9003 check
    server m5 127.0.0.1:9004 check
    server m6 127.0.0.1:9005 check
    server m7 127.0.0.1:9006 check
    server m8 127.0.0.1:9007 check
```

One other things. The Thrift servers are running in Supervisor which I have noticed some weirdness with. But I have tried just running the Thrift server not in supervisor and it still doesn't work.

I have tried all of the Thrift servers (TSimpleServer, TNonBlockingServer, TThreadedServer) all of them have the same problem.

**Update**

Running `tcpdump port 9000`

```
15:12:31.878502 IP ip-00.00.00.00.ec2.internal.cslistener > ip-11.11.11.11.ec2.internal.36206: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3433673377, win 0, length 0
15:12:33.878425 IP ip-11.11.11.11.ec2.internal.36207 > ip-00.00.00.00.ec2.internal.cslistener: Flags [S], seq 3459211721, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 440815982 ecr 0,nop,wscale 10], length 0
```

Where `00.00.00.00` is the server running the Thrift server and `11.11.11.11` is the server running HAProxy.
These 2 lines repeat continuously.

Running `netstat -tlnp` contains the following:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      19472/python
```

So the Thrift server is listening on the right port.

Comment: What do you see when you `tcpdump` on `127.0.0.1` port 9000?

Comment: A lot of this: `15:12:31.878502 IP ip-00.00.00.00.ec2.internal.cslistener > ip-11.11.11.11.ec2.internal.36206: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3433673377, win 0, length 0
15:12:33.878425 IP ip-11.11.11.11.ec2.internal.36207 > ip-00.00.00.00.ec2.internal.cslistener: Flags [S], seq 3459211721, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 440815982 ecr 0,nop,wscale 10], length 0` Where `00.00.00.00` is the server running the Thrift server and `11.11.11.11` is the server running HAProxy.

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough in that `tcpdump` to be sure but it looks like your health check is sending a `SYN` packet and is getting a `RST` packet in return.  (Feel free to post more of it in your actual question where you can format it properly.)

I suspect there's nothing listening on 127.0.0.1:9000 (or any of the other ports).

You can check this with `sudo netstat -tlnp`.

Either the Thrift servers are listening on different IP addresses and/or ports or they aren't listening at all.

Comment: I updated the question with the formatted out of tcpdump and netstat.